# Python Plotly - How to change the distance between the cursor and the information (annotation) box?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am using Plotly to chart a Sine wave (see code below). I would like to increase the distance between the cursor and its information box. Any help regarding how to change the distance is appreciated.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go 
import numpy as np
# Generate data for sine wave
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100) 
y = np.sin(x)
# Create figure
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=x, y=y)])
# Display the x and y values when moving the cursor.
fig.update_layout(hovermode = 'x unified')
#Show figure
fig.show()
```

Comment: There are three modes of hover labels. The default is `closet`. Besides that, there are `unified` and `axis` which you specify. Try the axis and set it if you like. Other than that, there are none at this time. See [this](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#hover-labels)

Comment: `hoverdistance` isn't a _start looking after 10 px_', it's a _look as far out as 10 px_. Since you plotted a continuous line, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. It seems like you intentionally want to hover over 'point a' and see the tooltip for 'point b'. Perhaps I just don't understand your question. Could you provide an image mock of what you're looking for? Or perhaps try to explain it another way?

Comment: Thank you Kat. I edited my posting and removed the distance statement. See my reply to Joel below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hoverdistance sets the distance to look for data to use for the hover label, rather than the distance of the hover label from the datapoint. So, you could remove that line as I don't think that's what you're trying to do.

There's no option to set the distance between the point and the hoverlabel as far as I'm aware, this is a reported issue here: [Reported issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3927)

One option may be to set the bgcolor to something that's transparent:

```
`fig.update_layout(hovermode = 'x unified', hoverlabel=dict(bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,0.1)'))`
```

At least that way you can still see the plot behind, if that's what your concern is about.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I removed the "distance" statement from the code. Because there is no option to set the distance between the point and the hover label, your idea to make the background transparent is very creative. More so, I tried it successfully and it is perhaps better than moving the label.